# iPhone 4S Gray Light in Middle of Black Screen Fix?

Tags: iphone, screen, graphics, charging

I'm having trouble with my iPhone 4S. It rarely turns on and whenever it does, it shows a gray light in the middle of a black screen with some kind of halo around the light. Also, whenever I hook it up to a charger, it makes the charging sound over and over and over, every 7 or 8 seconds. I was wondering if anyone has/had the same or similar problem? If so, any suggestions, other than repair? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tap it! I have one on my iPad. When you tap it it  brings up your control buttons, I.e. Home screen,notification centre or whichever you use for your iPhone. CAnt help with the charging noise, but perhaps it's incoming notifications?

Comment: its okay, I got it to work somehow by messing with the sim card slot and then restarting the phone. thanks though